# Got "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null" error

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, charts, scatter-plot

I am trying to draw a scatter plot chart with D3 from a csv file. The csv looks something like this:

```
location    smokeSomeDays   allFamPovPct
AL                5%             15%
AK                5%             8%
AZ                4%             13%
AR                6%             14%
CA                4%             12%
CO                4%             8%
CT                4%             8%
DE                4%             9%
DC                5%             14%
...
...
...
```

I want the Y-Axis to be 'smokeSomeDays' and the X-Axis to be 'allFamPovPct'

Here is my js that evokes the "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null" error, even though 'getAttribute' is not mentioned anywhere in the code:

```
var svgW = 960;
var svgH = 500;

var margin = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 60, left: 50 };

var chartWidth = svgW - margin.left - margin.right;
var chartHeight = svgH - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgW)
  .attr("height", svgH)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv('data.csv', function(data) {
  data.forEach(function () {
  // Scales
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.allFamPovPct })]),
      d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.allFamPovPct })])
      ])
    .range([0,chartWidth])
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.smokeSomeDays })]),
      d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.smokeSomeDays })])
      ])
    .range([chartHeight,0])
  // X-axis
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(5)
  // Y-axis
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale)
    .ticks(5)
  // Circles
  var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
     .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',function (d) { return xScale(d.allFamPovPct) })
      .attr('cy',function (d) { return yScale(d.smokeSomeDays) })
      .attr('r','10')
      .attr('stroke','black')
      .attr('stroke-width',1)
      .attr('fill')

  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + chartHeight + ')')
      .call(xAxis)
    .append('text') // X-axis Label
      .attr('class','label')
      .attr('y',-10)
      .attr('x',chartWidth)

  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .call(yAxis)
     .append('text') // y-axis Label
      .attr('class','label')
      .attr('transform','rotate(-90)')
      .attr('x',0)
      .attr('y',5)

});
});
```

The full error msg looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null  d3.min.js:4
at dt.ul [as attr] (d3.min.js:4)
at app.js:49
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at app.js:17
at d3.min.js:3
at Object.<anonymous> (d3.min.js:7)
at v.call (d3.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.min.js:7)
```

But all the lines mentioned in the error looks good to me, maybe I'm missing something.

The code also doesn't produce a scatter plot that I want. It gives me something like this:

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
O ---------------------------------------
```

Here is my html, if it helps:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Data Journalism</title>
<style>
.chart {

}

.main text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;  
}

.axis circle, .axis path {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;
}

circle {
    fill: steelblue;
}

</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.3/d3.min.js">
</script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class='content'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: the error is most likely being thrown by the library you are using

Comment: Check app.js line 49

Comment: What happens if you remove the data.forEach loop?

Comment: You have somewhere `.attr('fill')`. But you should provide the fill color as a second argument (or a URL like `.attr('fill', 'url(#pic)')`).

Comment: @trincot suspiciously that is line 49

Comment: *"not mentioned anywhere in the code"* --- Well you include libraries that do have it.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get right now is due to the fact that...

```
.attr("fill")
```

... is a **getter**, not a setter. Have in mind that this error is thrown by D3 library, but your console shows the line of **your** code that is the actual culprit.

However, this is the least of your problems here.

The first big problem is that `forEach` inside the callback. That is completely unnecessary in a D3 code. Get rid of it.

The second problem is that `smokeSomeDays` and `allFamPovPct` are **strings**, not numbers. You have to convert them to numbers to use your scale. Here, in this example, I'm using a row function:

```
function(d){
    d.smokeSomeDays = +d.smokeSomeDays.split("%")[0];
    d.allFamPovPct = +d.allFamPovPct.split("%")[0];
    return d;
}
```

Here is your code with those changes (and just a couple of rows of your CSV):

```js
var csv = `location,smokeSomeDays,allFamPovPct
AL,5%,15%
AK,5%,8%
AZ,4%,13%
AR,6%,14%`;

var svgW = 400;
var svgH = 300;

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 50
};

var chartWidth = svgW - margin.left - margin.right;
var chartHeight = svgH - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgW)
  .attr("height", svgH)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.smokeSomeDays = +d.smokeSomeDays.split("%")[0];
  d.allFamPovPct = +d.allFamPovPct.split("%")[0];
  return d;
})

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    d3.min([0, d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.allFamPovPct
    })]),
    d3.max([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.allFamPovPct
    })])
  ])
  .range([0, chartWidth])
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    d3.min([0, d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.smokeSomeDays
    })]),
    d3.max([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.smokeSomeDays
    })])
  ])
  .range([chartHeight, 0])
  // X-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(5)
  // Y-axis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .ticks(5)
  // Circles
var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.allFamPovPct)
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return yScale(d.smokeSomeDays)
  })
  .attr('r', '10')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + chartHeight + ')')
  .call(xAxis)
  .append('text') // X-axis Label
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('y', -10)
  .attr('x', chartWidth)

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text') // y-axis Label
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 5)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with loading library multiple times/initialising same id multiple times